# How to load JSON config file in cement python app?

Tags: python, json, configuration, cement

I have just started using cement as a python framework. It seems that the default config of the app is not JSON.

It seems that Cement has `JsonConfigHandler()` class that could load JSON configuration into app. I have used the code below in my app:

```
ins = JsonConfigHandler()
ins.parse_file('/etc/luna/luna.conf')
```

But it gives the error below:

```
    return self._parse_file(file_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cement/ext/ext_json.py", line 243, in _parse_file
    self.merge(self._json.load(open(file_path)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Hows should I load JSON config file in cement app?

By default I load config using `app.config.parse_file('/etc/my_app/app.conf')` with no problem and config file contains:

```
[connection]
host=172.16.131.12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for not being on top of this, but here is the official response (primary developer):

You simply need to include the `json` extension, and then set the `CementApp.Meta.config_handler` to `json`:

```
from cement.core.foundation import CementApp

class MyApp(CementApp):
    class Meta:
        label = 'myapp'
        extensions = ['json']
        config_handler = 'json'
        config_extension = '.json'
```

This will keep the default `config_files` list intact, but use `.json` instead of `.conf` for the files it looks for.

Answer (score 1):

JSON file `/etc/luna/luna.conf`:

```
{
    "connection": {
        "host": "172.16.131.12"
    }
}
```

Python:

```
from cement.core.foundation import CementApp
from cement.ext.ext_json import JsonConfigHandler

app = CementApp('test', config_handler=JsonConfigHandler,
                config_files=['/etc/luna/luna.conf'])
app.setup()

print(app.config.get('connection', 'host'))
```

Outputs `172.16.131.12`

---

**Old answer, please disregard**

Don't know the library, but looking at the code it looks like you have to first call the `_setup()` method:

```
ins = JsonConfigHandler()
ins._setup(app)
ins.parse_file('/etc/luna/luna.conf')
```

Comment: Inside of Cement framework calling a protected method does not seem good practice at all. I'm sure there is a better way that could feed JSON config into cement configuration handler.

Comment: You are absolutely right @ALH, can you check if the edit I added works?

Comment: @ALH made another edit, it now works correctly for me. Let me know if this works for you and I'll edit the answer to reflect the correct solution clearly.

Comment: Thank you for your response, If in JSON I have a key like `"modern": "yes"` how should I retrieve it? It seems that a config should have a section! I cannot get `modern` by get() method.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, if you have a look at the code the `cement.ext.ext_json.JsonConfigHandler#_parse_file` method loads the JSON config file (`self._json.load(open(file_path))`) and passes the JSON object (a dict) to `cement.ext.ext_configparser.ConfigParserConfigHandler#merge`, this method iterates over the key value pairs of the JSON dict and skips the ones where the value isn't a dict. I guess you will have to put `"modern": "yes"` inside a section. 

I didn't find documentation for this, it's all from what I understand from reading the code, and therefore I could be wrong.